# Get information between two strings

Tags: php, string

I have the following PHP string

```
$string = "Hello World<br>- 8/7/2013<br>Hello World";
```

So basically, I need to get the information between a dash and space (`-`) and the closest line break tag. Your help is very much appreciated! I looked for hours but haven't been successful. I don't think that `preg_replace` would help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) finds the index of a substring (optionally after a specified index), so:

```
$start = strpos($string, '- ') + 2;
$end   = strpos($string, '<br>', $start);
$part  = substr($string, $start, $end - $start);
```

[Ta-da!](http://codepad.org/goQdvarN)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_match`:

```
if(preg_match("~-\s(.*?)<br>~", $string, $matches)) {
    $data = $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: It’s probably a good idea to use a single-quoted string for regular expressions (even if `\s` here isn’t an escape sequence in PHP).

Comment: you should change the `<br>` something that would catch any form of `<br>`, `<br/>`, `<br />`; maybe just `<br` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getData($haystack) {
    $dash = strpos($haystack, "- ") + 2;
    $br = strpos($haystack, "<br>", $dash);
    return substr($haystack, $dash, $br - $dash);
}
```

Comment: `substr`’s third argument is length, not ending index.